# Causal Impact in Python giving error: exog contains inf or nans

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I have the following dataset.

```
     y          X
0   70.0      10.0
1   59.0      10.0
2   40.0      10.0
3   56.0      10.0
4   46.0      10.0
5   65.0      10.0
6   60.0      10.0
7   45.0      10.0
8   55.0  555267.0
9   69.0  558056.0
10  64.0  176734.0
```

When I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from causalimpact import CausalImpact

y1 = [70.0, 59.0, 40.0, 56.0, 46.0, 65.0, 60.0, 45.0, 55.0, 69.0, 64.0]

X1 = [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5552675.0, 5580561.0, 1767342.0]

y = np.array(y1)
X = np.array(X1)

y[8:] += 5

data = pd.DataFrame({'y': y, 'X': X}, columns=['y', 'X'])

pre_period = [0, 7]
post_period = [8, 10]

ci = CausalImpact(data, pre_period, post_period)
print(ci.summary())
print(ci.summary(output='report'))
ci.plot()
```

I get the error:  exog contains inf or nans

Any resolution to this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by having too many identical values in your `X1` array. If you change any of your `10.0` to a, say, `11.0`, the problem disappears.

Comment: In fact, to be more precise, the problem is that you _only_ have identical values in the `pre_period` subset of your `X1` array (`X1[0:8] = [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0]`).

Comment: Thanks @David M. It works now. Another quick question, how can I change the confidence interval in the CausalImpact function. Default value is 95%. I want 90%

Comment: `ci = CausalImpact(data=data, pre_period=pre_period, post_period=post_period, alpha=0.1)`